# JEditorPane is not resizable after changing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, resize, gridbaglayout, jeditorpane

I have some Components like JTextArea, JTextfield, etc. in a GridBagLayout.
But the JEditoPane won't resizes after minimizing the size of my JFrame.

Is there a solution to solve it? Or any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: ok I solved it be myself with JTextPane